# Mac terminal writes these lines every time I build Jekyll site

Tags: build, terminal, jekyll

Every time I build my site with Jekyll through the terminal (Mac), everything works fine but theses lines show up:

```
[2013-02-21 16:17:38] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-02-21 16:17:38] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08) [universal-darwin11.0]
[2013-02-21 16:18:38] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=897 port=4000
```

Then I'm unable to enter anything – the little grey square is displayed, but not the name of my computer followed by a semicolon as usual. If I want to type something again, I need to close/reopen the terminal window with this message:

"Closing this window will terminate the running processes: login, bash, ruby."

Please, note that I'm not a terminal stuff expert ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What command are you using to build the site? What you see on those 3 lines is a local webserver that is running and serving your site. If you are running `jekyll --server` you'll get this webserver; open `localhost:4000` in your browser and you'll see your site.

If you just want to generate the site, just run `jekyll` without the `--server` flag.

In the terminal you can cancel any running processes, such as the webserver, by pressing Ctrl-C. That way you don't need to close the window if you accidentally run the wrong command.

Comment: I've used `jekyll --server`. I just tested without the `--server`and everything works now. I'm beginning and I have to say, it's kind of stupid to append `--server` to `jekyll` command because I'm not working with MAMP for those tests. Thanks Brand!